# Get text after 'x' and before ''y' in Excel

Tags: excel, string, text-extraction

I have a source .csv file which is non-editable, I'd like to extract the quantity that is enclosed within a particular text. I've tried using `MID` with a combination of `LEFT` and `RIGHT`. However, I've only been able to get either of them (before / after).

I'd like to extract the text after `QTY :` and anything before `)`

Example:

```
(Empty : Empty - Colour : Mixed colours - QTY : 22)
```

The text I'm interested in is - "22"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use combination of mid and find functions

> =MID(A1,FIND("QTY :",A1)+LEN("QTY :"),(FIND(")",A1) - (FIND("QTY :",A1)+LEN("QTY :"))))

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of this formula:

```
=SUM(MID(0&A1,LARGE(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+1,1)*10^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))/10)
```

Credits go [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/443983-extract-only-numbers-text-string.html).